# How to get multiple COUNT(*) queries in different tables in one?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I've been trying to get 4 or more COUNT(*) queries from different tables **into one query**.

Is this even possible or do I have to make four different queries?

This is my code:

```
try (final PreparedStatement sel = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(coins) FROM User");
            final PreparedStatement sel2 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Friends");
            final PreparedStatement sel3 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Clans");
            final PreparedStatement sel4 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ClanMembers")) {
        try (final ResultSet rs = sel.executeQuery(); final ResultSet rs2 = sel2.executeQuery(); final ResultSet rs3 = sel3.executeQuery()) {
            rs.last();
            rs2.last();
            rs3.last();
            return new Object[] { rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), rs2.getInt(1) / 2, rs3.getInt(1) };
        }
}
```

Comment: UNION ALL, or JOIN the sub-queries.

Comment: Using `UNION ALL` is the simplest solution to me but you have one query with 2 column ... so this will not work. so using sub-queries is one solution. FYI : You could use a `Statement` if you don't pass any parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(coins) FROM User
union all
SELECT COUNT(*), 0 FROM Friends
union all
SELECT COUNT(*), 0 FROM Clans
union all
SELECT COUNT(*), 0 FROM ClanMembers
...
```

Amount and types of columns must be the same for all unioned queries

Answer updated to show how to combine the queries.

Comment: Look the first query ;) there is a COUNT and a SUM. So your statement is actually telling he can't use this. But that match the quersion title ... so I guess this is valid ... I give you that !

Comment: Thanks!
I noticed you added some zeros. Probably so the union works out.
Will I have to ignore the zeros while going through the result set?
Or won't they appear in my resultset?

Comment: To union queries they must have the same amount of columns and types. So if the first query has 2 columns then the second must also have 2 columns - that's why 0 value for the second column was added

Answer (score 4):

Just give another optional solution
(i can't comment yet so i have to write as answer)

StanislavL's answer is a nice answer, you can use it, it will return (n) row

but just in case if you need just 1 row
you can try this

```
SELECT q1.count1,q1.coins,q2.count2, q3.count3, q4.count4
from (select (COUNT(*) count1, SUM(coins) coins, 1 id FROM User, 1 var) q1
inner join (SELECT COUNT(*) count2, 1 id FROM Friends) q2 on q1.id=q2.id
inner join (SELECT COUNT(*) count3, 1 id FROM Clans) q3 on q1.id=q3.id
inner join (SELECT COUNT(*) count4, 1 id FROM ClanMembers) q4 on q1.id=q4.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that I missed the obvious answer.

This solved my problem:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User
union all
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Friends
union all
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Clans
union all
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ClanMembers
union all
SELECT SUM(coins) FROM User
...`